# Jquery Required fields - no plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering what the javascript/jquery is to make a field in a form a required field?

Comment: Do a Google search first and ask about a specific library/problem. We can't infer what plugin will meet your needs.

Comment: I didn't want a plugin, I wanted straight jquery/javascript. I'm sorry I was so vague, but there's not much else to ask really. I did a google search for a few different things.

Comment: That's cool. A good plan then is to say what you've tried, what you've thought about, or where you're stuck.

Also, even if you didn't want a plugin for whatever reason, looking at what people have built with Jquery is often very instructive and offers lots of inspiration.

Answer (score 9):

```
<input type="text" data-required="true">
```

Then using jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var faults = $('input').filter(function() {
        // filter input elements to required ones that are empty
        return $(this).data('required') && $(this).val() === "";
    }).css("background-color", "red"); // make them attract the eye
    if(faults.length) return false; // if any required are empty, cancel submit
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evpS9/1/

Comment: Hi, I've tried this and it doesn't seem to be working, but this may be because rather than change the css, I'm trying to change the text of a paragraph - $('p.validation_error').text("Please enter a valid name");

Comment: @snakespan: What 'isn't working' and how isn't it working? Does my fiddle work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It's not nice to downvote without comments guys. You're getting downvoted because your question is very vague and lacks a simple google search with that exact question.

What you are looking for (possibly) is jQuery Validator